# Speed up/slow down audio file

Tags: sound, editing

I am importing an audiofile to Mathematica and want to play it back at double speed. The only functions I see are the advanced options of AudioPitchShift (which doesn't alter the duration but increases the pitch) and AudioTimeStretch (which doesn't alter the pitch but does alter the duration). However, I want it both at the same time, half the duration, double the pitch. Which function should I use?

Comment: Can't you compose those two together, with a judicious setting of options, to achieve the result you want ?  ie, something like `AudioTimeStretch[AudioPitchShift[myaudiofile, dp], 0.5]`

Comment: Yes I can, but I suspect there is a faster & simpler option which I am overlooking

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same. The best I came up with is this (replace `a` with your audio):

```
AudioPlay[Audio[AudioData[a],SampleRate->AudioSampleRate[a]*2]]
```